# MLP - how to easily find Derpy and the changelings?

Tags: my-little-pony

I want to find Derpy more often and I need the changelings for my quest.

Comment: You are asking too much. For *one* question. You can post *more than one* question on this site and this is what you should do with this question. Split it onto at least two. Finding Derpy and changelings are rather similar, so those both should propably stay here. But you should ask about Chyrsalis and Luna in seperate question. Also, remember that you can always edit your questions to improve them. In this case, remove the additional question once you've created the new one.

Comment: Actually I'll get the Chrysalis by defeating the changelings.